How to Update the Contents of a Dropdown Based on the Selection of Another Dropdown
I am trying to update the contents of a particular dropdown box, based on the selection of another dropdown box. The contents of these boxes is coming from tables in an MSSQL database. Basically, I have a list of "Principals" (aka companies) in one box, and a "Description" box (aka different items) in a second box. My goal is that one you select a specific "Principal" (aka company), that only the selected Principal's items populate the "Description" box. As it stands now, every item in the "Description" box displays, regardless of the "Principal" (aka company) selected. Just to give you an idea, below is a screenshot of the boxes I am referring to, as well as the relevant code currently being used. As you can obviously see, it's written mainly in asp-classic/vbs, but Javascript is used as well. I am open to using ANY language/method necessary to accomplish this. Any help is greatly appreciated, if any other details are required I am happy to give them. Thank you very much.

And here is the relevant code for the page currently being used:
<%
Dim Conn, Rs, strPrincipleOptions, DistributorOptions, SalesRepOptions, DescriptionOptions, strSQL
Dim rsclient, OperatorNumber, oRequest

    OperatorNumber = Request("Operator_Num") '12600 'test operator number
    ProcessMe = Cbool(Request("ProcessMe"))

    If (OperatorNumber = "") then
        Call TryAgain
    ElseIf Cbool(ProcessMe) Then
    
        Set Conn = Application("Conn")
        Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

        For each oRequest in Request.Form
            If (oRequest <> "ProcessMe") AND (oRequest <> "submit") AND (Left(oRequest,4) <> "temp") then
                If (Request.Form(oRequest) <> "") Then
                    strNames = strNames & oRequest & ","
                    If (Left(oRequest,9) = "Principle") OR (Left(oRequest,11) = "Distributor") then 
                        strValues = strValues & Request.Form(oRequest) & ","
                    Else
                        strValues = strValues & "'" & Replace(Request.Form(oRequest),"'","") & "',"
                    End if
                End If
            End If
        Next
        strNames = Left(strNames,Len(strNames)-1) & ",[date]"
        strValues = Left(strValues,Len(strValues)-1) & ",'" & date() & "'"
        
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO Product (" & strNames & ") VALUES (" & strValues & ")"
        'Response.Write strSQL
        'Response.End
        
        Conn.Execute (strSQL)
        Set Conn = nothing

        Call SubmittedReport
        '+INSERT INTO "Product" ("Operator_Num", "Operator", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Contact1", "Phone", "creation_date", "Type_Call", "Acc_Rep", "Sales_Rep", "Mgmt_Co", "Segment", "DSR_Pri", "DSRFullName_Pri", "Concept_Recipe", "Product1", "Product2", "Product3", "Product4", "Product5", "Product6", "Description1", "Description2", "Description3", "Description4", "Description5", "Description6", "Principle1", "Principle2", "Principle3", "Principle4", "Principle5", "Principle6", "Result1", "Result2", "Result3", "Result4", "Result5", "Result6", "Cases1", "Cases2", "Cases3", "Cases4", "Cases5", "Cases6", "Distributor1", "Distributor2", "Distributor3", "Distributor4", "Distributor5", "Distributor6", "Comments1", "Comments2", "Comments3", "Comments4", "Comments5", "Comments6", "FollowUp_Date", "FollowUp_Necessary")
        '+VALUES ('%Operator_Num%', '%Operator%', '%Address%', '%City%', '%State%', '%Zip%', '%Contact1%', '%Phone%', '%creation_date%', '%Type_Call%', '%Acc_Rep%', '%Sales_Rep%', '%Mgmt_Co%', '%Segment%', '%DSR_Pri%', '%DSRFullName_Pri%', '%Concept_Recipe%', '%Product1%', '%Product2%', '%Product3%', '%Product4%', '%Product5%', '%Product6%', '%Description1%', '%Description2%', '%Description3%', '%Description4%', '%Description5%', '%Description6%', '%Principle1%', '%Principle2%', '%Principle3%', '%Principle4%', '%Principle5%', '%Principle6%', '%Result1%', '%Result2%', '%Result3%', '%Result4%', '%Result5%', '%Result6%', '%Cases1%', '%Cases2%', '%Cases3%', '%Cases4%', '%Cases5%', '%Cases6%', '%Distributor1%', '%Distributor2%', '%Distributor3%', '%Distributor4%', '%Distributor5%', '%Distributor6%', '%Comments1%', '%Comments2%', '%Comments3%', '%Comments4%', '%Comments5%', '%Comments6%', '%FollowUp_Date%', '%FollowUp_Necessary%');
        
    Else        
        Set Conn = Application("Conn")
        Set rsclient = Conn.execute ("select * from FSA where Operator_Num = "& OperatorNumber)

        If rsclient.eof then
            Call TryAgain
        End If

        Call getDropdowns
        Call CallReport
    End If
            
Sub getDropdowns
    Set Conn = Application("Conn")
    Set Rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Principle), ID FROM Principal ORDER BY Principal.Principle"
    Rs.Open strSQL, Conn
    Do while not Rs.EOF
        strPrincipleOptions = strPrincipleOptions & "<option value=" & Rs.Fields("ID") & ">" & Rs.Fields("Principle") & "</option>" & vbcrlf
    Rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    Rs.Close
            
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Distributor), ID FROM Distributors ORDER BY Distributor"
    Rs.Open strSQL, Conn
    Do while not Rs.EOF
        DistributorOptions = DistributorOptions & "<option value=" & Rs.Fields("ID") & ">" & Rs.Fields("Distributor") & "</option>" & vbcrlf
    Rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    Rs.Close
            
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(FullName) FROM sales_rep ORDER BY FullName"
    Rs.Open strSQL, Conn
    Do while not Rs.EOF
        SalesRepOptions = SalesRepOptions & "<option value=" & chr(34)  & Rs.Fields("FullName") & chr(34)  & ">" & Rs.Fields("Fullname") & "</option>" & vbcrlf
    Rs.MoveNext
    Loop    
    Rs.Close

    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Description) FROM Item_Desc ORDER BY Description"
    Rs.Open strSQL, Conn
    Do while not Rs.EOF
        DescriptionOptions = DescriptionOptions & "<option value=" & chr(34)  & Rs.Fields("Description") & chr(34)  & ">" & Rs.Fields("Description") & "</option>" & vbcrlf
    Rs.MoveNext
    Loop    
    Rs.Close

End Sub

Sub CallReport
    %>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>FoodService Call Report</title>
    <script language=javascript>

    function on_load() {
            window.scroll(0,0);
            document.update.Sales_Rep.focus();
    }

    function getCreation_Date() {

        if (document.update.Sales_Rep.value == "") {
        alert ("You must select a Sales Rep before submitting document.");
                            window.scroll(0,0)
                            document.update.Sales_Rep.focus();
            return;
        }
            //date1 must be a 0 or 1        
            if (parseInt(document.update.temp2.value) > 12)  {
                            alert ("You did not enter a valid MONTH.");
                            document.update.temp2.value = "";
                            window.scroll(0,0)
                            document.update.temp2.focus();
                    return;
            } 
            //date3 must be a 0 or 1 or 2 or 3
            
            var temp_date =      document.update.temp2.value + "/" +
                                    document.update.temp4.value + "/" +
                                    document.update.temp5.value +
                                    document.update.temp6.value +
                                    document.update.temp7.value +
                                    document.update.temp8.value 
        if (temp_date.length < 8) {
                    alert ("You did not enter a correct Call Date. i.e. 01/01/2003");
                    window.scroll(0,0)
                    document.update.temp2.focus();
                    return;
            } else {
                    

            var creation_date = temp_date;
                    document.update.creation_date.value = temp_date;//creation_date
                    document.update.submit();
            }
    }

    //  <input type="button" value="Insert Record" name=jerry onClick="getCreation_Date();">&nbsp; &nbsp;
    //  &nbsp;<input TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear" id=reset1 name=reset1></p>

    </script>
    </head>

<body BACKGROUND="../tabbkgnd.jpg" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#4E7F6E" VLINK="#1B4E3B">

    <b><font size="5" color="blue">

    <p align="center">FoodService Associates</font><br>
    <font size="3" color="black">Call Report Information (Use TAB key to move to next field)</font></b>
    <b>

     <table border="1" cellpadding="4" Width="95%" align="center">
        <!-- HIDE THE FORM SPACE -->
        <form action="updateclientA.asp" method="post" name="update">
          <input type="hidden" name="ProcessMe" value=1>
          <!--<input type="hidden" name="[Date]" value="<%=Date()%>">-->
          <input type="hidden" name="Operator_Num" value="<%response.write(rsclient("Operator_num"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="Acc_Rep" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Acc_Rep"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="Operator" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Operator"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="Address" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Address"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="City" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("City"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="State" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("State"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="Zip" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Zip"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="Contact1" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Contact1"))%>">
              
          <input type="hidden" maxlength=100 name="Phone" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Phone"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="Mgmt_Co" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Mgmt_Co"))%>">
          <input type="hidden" name="Segment" value="<%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Segment"))%>">

        <tr bgcolor="yellow">
          <td align="right">
            <b>Call Date: 
            mm<input type="text" value="<%=Month(date())%>" size="2" maxlength="2" name="temp2" onKeyUp="">/ 
            dd<input type="text" value="<%=day(date())%>" size="2" maxlength="2" name="temp4" onKeyUp="">/ 
            yy<input type="text" value="2" size="1" maxlength="1" name="temp5"> 
            <input type="text" value="0" size="1" maxlength="1" name="temp6"> 
            <input type="text" value="2" size="1" maxlength="1" name="temp7"> 
            <input type="text" value="4" size="1" maxlength="1" name="temp8">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="creation_date"> 
            </b></td>
          <td align="right"><b>Operator/ Mgmt Co #:</b></td>
          <td><%=rsclient("Operator_num")%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><b>Class:</b></td>
          <td><%=rsclient("A_Class")%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="1" cellpadding="1" Width="95%" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Assigned Rep:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Acc_Rep"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Sales Rep:</b></font></td>
          <td><select name="Sales_Rep" size="1">
            <option selected value="">Select</option>
            <%response.write SalesRepOptions%>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Operator:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Operator"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Mgmt Co.:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Mgmt_Co"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Address:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Address"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>City:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("City"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>State:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("State"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Zip Code:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Zip"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Phone:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Phone"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Fax:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Fax"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>1st Contact:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Contact1"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>2nd Contact:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Contact2"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      
 <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>1st Contact Title:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Contact_Title1"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>2nd Contact Title:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Contact_Title2"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
<tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>1st Contact Phone:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Contact_P1"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>2nd Contact Phone:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Contact_P2"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>1st Contact Email:</b></font></td>
          <td><a href = mailto:><%response.write (rsclient("Contact1_Mail"))%> &nbsp;</td></a>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>2nd Contact Email:</b></font></td>
          <td><a href = mailto:><%response.write (rsclient("Contact2_mail"))%> &nbsp;</td></a>
                         
     </tr> 
         <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Segment:</b></font></td>         
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Segment"))%> &nbsp;</td></a>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Affiliation:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("Affiliation"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>Pri. DSTR:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("DSR_Pri"))%> &nbsp;</td>
          <td align="right"><font size="2"><b>DSR Name:</b></font></td>
          <td><%response.write UCASE(rsclient("DSRFullName_Pri"))%> &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <font color="red"><b><div align="center"><center><p>CALL REPORT<font color="black">
      </center></div><table border="1" cellpadding="4" Width="95%" align="center">
        <tr bgcolor="yellow">
          <td><div align="center"><center><p><b>&nbsp; &nbsp;<font color="#FF0000">Is 
            this an "<i>issued</i>" SALES LEAD</font><font color="#FF00FF"> 
            </font>&nbsp; <input type="radio"
          name="Type_Call" Value="YES"> YES &nbsp; &nbsp; <input
          type="radio" name="Type_Call" Value=""> NO&nbsp; <font color="#FF0000">
            (&quot;issued&quot; defined as a formal Lead recorded with the Sales 
            Administrator in the office)</font></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
          <td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
        </tr>
         <tr bgcolor="yellow">
          <td><div align="center"><center><p><b>&nbsp; &nbsp;</font></font><font color="#FF0000">Check Only If a NOW OBJECTIVE Operator Call:</font> <font color="red">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="radio"
          name="Type_Call2" Value="NOW"> </font>NOW Objective Call  <font color="red">&nbsp; &nbsp; <input
          type="radio" name="Type_Call2" Value=""> </font><font color="#FF0000">
            <u>Not</u>
              </font>a<font color="#FF0000"> </font>NOW Objective</b>
          </div>
        </center></td>
        </tr><tr align="center"><td> &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>&nbsp;</font></b><font color="RED"><span style="font-style: normal; font-weight: 700">MARKED 
          FIELDS ARE REQUIRED ENTRIES ***</span></td></tr>
      </table>
      <font color="red">
      <div align="center"><center>
        <table border="1" width="95%" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tr bgcolor="yellow">
          <td width="23">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="95"><b><font size="2">Product#<font color="#FF0000"> </font></font>
          </b></td>
          <td width="211"><b><font size="2">Description<font color="#FF0000">
          </font></font><font color="#FF0000">***</font></b></td>
          <td width="117"><b><font size="2">Principal<font color="#FF0000">
          </font></font><font color="#FF0000">***</font></b></td>
          <td width="95"><b><font size="2">Result<font color="#FF0000"> </font></font>
          <font color="#FF0000">***</font></b></td>
          <td width="70"><font size="2"><b>Cases</b></font></td>
          <td width="115"><font size="2"><b>Distributor</b></font></td>
          <td width="293"><font size="2"><b>Comments</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="23"><font size="2"><b>1:</b></font></td>
          <td width="95"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="30" name="Product1"></td>
          <td width="211"><select name="Description1" size="1">
            <option selected value="0">select</option>
            <%response.write DescriptionOptions%>
            <option value="">55</option>
          </select></td>
          <td width="117"><select name="Principle1" size="1">
            <option selected value="0">select</option>
            <%response.write strPrincipleOptions%>
            <option value="">55</option>
          </select></td>
          <td width="250"><select name="Result1" size="1">
            <option selected value="Select">Select</option>
            <option value="Sold">Sold</option>
            <option value="Testing">Testing</option>
            <option value="Interest">Interest</option>
            <option value="Using">Using</option>
            <option value="Intent To Use">Intent To Use</option>
            <option value="No Taste">No Taste</option>
            <option value="No Price">No Price</option>
            <option value="No Pend Dist">No Pend Dist</option>
            <option value="No Nutrition">No Nutrition</option>
            <option value="No Scratch">No Scratch</option>
            <option value="No Menu Fit">No Menu Fit</option>
            <option value="Follow Up Needed">Follow Up Needed</option>
            <option value="re-Order (sold)">re-Order (sold)</option>
            </select></td>
          <td width="70"><input type="text" size="4" maxlength="30" name="Cases1"></td>
          <td width="115"><select name="Distributor1" size="1">
            <option selected value="0">select</option>
            <%response.write DistributorOptions%>
          <option value="67">Other</option> 
          </select></td>
          <td width="290">
          <input type="text" size="36" maxlength="100" name="Comments1"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>


Edit: added a PHP example at the bottom
To make a set of <option> depend on the content of another field (in this case, another <option>), you have to generate <option> sets separately server-side, and dynamically administrate the content client-side.
Generation
This implies in generating one separate set of <option> from Descriptions for every Principal. I guess you would have, in your Item_Desc table, a field like Principle. Something like this:



ID
Principle
Description




1
Food
gelly


2
Drink
water


3
Food
butter


4
Drink
coffee


5
Drink
tea


6
Food
bread



So you would do:
"SELECT DISTINCT(Description), ID, Principle FROM Item_Desc ORDER BY Principle, Description"
Then, you would separate items according with the corresponding Principle. What you will actually generate depends of the method you choose below.
You would have two main ways of doing it:

Pre-generate the content, and send everything onto the page at first load, then use javascript to exchange content in real time, according to the selection of the Principal.

Upon the change of the principal, make an AJAX call to your database, and load the result directly into the <option> of Description.


The advantage of pre-generation is that changes in the Principal <option> are immediately reflected to the Description. The con is that it might take longer for the page the load, it you have a lot of Description options. Another catch is that pre-generation is not realtime: if an option is added to the database in the meantime, it wont reflect onto your page until next load. So, if you are worried that Descriptions loaded are always updated, you're only way is to shift to AJAX.
In any case, you should trigger changes through the ONCHANGE listener in the <select> of the Principal:
<select name="Principle1" size="1" onchange="update_principal(this.selectedIndex)">

Pre-generation
You would have several ways of doing it. Perhaps load into a <DIV STYLE='display:none'>, or directly unto a javascript variable. The easiest form is using the JSON structure for that. You could have an array in which every key is a Principal, and values are the descriptions.
I don't know ASP, but if I were to write it in PHP, it would be like this:
 $descriptions = array();
 while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     if (isset($descriptions[$line['Principle']])) {
         $descriptions[$line['Principle']][] = $line['Description'];
     } else {
         $descriptions[$line['Principle']] = array($line['Description']);
     }
 }

You now have an array with all your options. In the page load, you could do something like that (again, within a PHP example):
<script type="text/javascript">
var descriptions = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($descriptions); ?>");
</script>

Then, your update_principal() function could look something like this:
function update_principal(principal) {
   document.getElementsByName("Description1")[0].options = descriptions[principal];
}

You're done.
AJAX
For that, you would need a page that selects descriptions based on input, and returns only that content.
function update_principal(principal) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            load_descriptions(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    // change url with your page
    xhttp.open("GET", url+"?principle="+principal, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

Then you would have the AJAX callback:
function load_descriptions(descriptions) {
   document.getElementsByName("Description1")[0].options = descriptions;
}

Server-side, the routine would be slightly adapted to filter only matching descriptions, preferably altering the SQL statement to this:
"SELECT DISTINCT(Description), ID FROM Item_Desc WHERE Principle = '".$_GET['principal']."' ORDER BY Description"
AJAX example in PHP
Note: in modern browsers, you would rather use fetch() instead of AJAX (using the old XMLHttpRequest()), while older browsers (IE, for instance) don't support fetch().

index.php
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("server_address","username","password","database_name");
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT(Principle), ID FROM Principal ORDER BY Principal.Principle");
$strPrincipleOptions = "";
while ($fields = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $strPrincipleOptions .= "<option value=".$fields["ID"].">".$fields["Principle"]."</option>\n";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="Principle1" onchange="update_principal(this.selectedIndex)">
        <option selected value="0">select</option>
        <?php echo $strPrincipleOptions; ?>
    </select>
    <select name="Description1">
        <option selected value="0">select a principal first</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>

Note the onchange listener of the <select>, calling the update_principal() function.

functions.js
function update_principal(principal) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            load_descriptions(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    // change url with your page
    var url = "https://www.mypage.com/";
    xhttp.open("GET", url+"webservice.php?principal="+principal, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
function load_descriptions(descriptions) {
    document.getElementsByName("Description1")[0].options = descriptions;
}

Notice the AJAX call to webservice.php: this is the script which returns an option set of Descriptions for the selected Principal. Notice also the callback load_descriptions(): it is executed as soon as the Descriptions were returned by the server.

webservice.php
<?php
if (isset($_GET["principal"])) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect("server_address","username","password","database_name");
    $rs = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT(Description), ID FROM Item_Desc WHERE Principle = '".$_GET['principal']."' ORDER BY Description");
    $DescriptionOptions = "<option value='0'>select</option>\n";
    while ($fields = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $DescriptionOptions .= "<option value=".$fields["ID"].">".$fields["Description"]."</option>\n";
    }
    echo $DescriptionOptions;
} else {
    echo "<option value='0'>no principal selected</option>\n";
}
?>


Oh my goodness you are amazing. First off, I just want to say how beyond grateful I am for your time and extremely thorough answer. I do have one question/clarification, and please forgive my ignorance. For the AJAX method, when you say “For that, you would need a page that selects descriptions based on input, and returns only that content,” you just mean by executing the suggested code, I would have a page that selects descriptions based on input correct? Like, you don’t mean I need to create a separate file (via include etc.) to execute this AJAX code, correct?

@kingklick You have to imagine an AJAX call like a "under the hood" navigation: the browser will call a url (exactly like you would, in a separate tab on your browser) and store the result (the HTML produced by the page) in a variable (the xhttp.responseText in my example) that you may manipulate with the callback you set (in my example, the load_descriptions() function). So, basically, yes, you would need to set a specific file, with a piece of code, only to retrieve the data you need and feed it back to the browser. I'm sorry I can't answer that in ASP, but feel free to ask a PHP example.

I mentioned in my OP but likely wasn't clear enough (sorry), that the columns needed for Principal (the company) and Item_Desc (the products) are inside two different tables. The column inside Principal is called Principle, and the column inside Item_Desc is called Description. How would this change the code (especially the SQL code) in your awesome post? It is still possible to achieve my goal with them being from two different tables hopefully? Thank you very much for your help.

@kingklick You can have different tables, as long as you have some way to link them. Typically, your Item_Desc table would have at least three fields: numeric id, Description, and the Principle to which this specific Description belongs. Or else, how do you know that "bread", "butter" and "gelly" belong to "Food", while "water", "milk" and "cofee" belong to "Drink"?

@kingklick I just added an example of table structure to achieve the link between tables, and an example of PHP code for the AJAX call. Hope this helps.

Yes that makes sense. Sorry for the confusion. That’s exactly how I have the table structured. Glad I was on the right track in that regard. Now it’s time for me to get to work on the rest of it, especially converting your very helpful php to asp-classic. Thanks again for all your help so far, it’s very much appreciated!

After working on this, I realized the best, and hopefully simplest, way to go about this would be to have all of the Principles (Companies) in one dropdown box, and when you select one of these companies, that same box repopulates now showing all of the items that belong to that Principle (Company). I'd be super grateful if you could update your post to reflect how I would go about this. P.S. I don't see a way to send a PM on here, so if you could give me your email address or social media, I'd love to buy you a cup of coffee (or two or three) :) Thank you so much.

@kingklick To load the items into the same dropdown, you would only change the element which receives the data, in the callback load_descriptions(): document.getElementsByName("Principle1")[0].options = descriptions. Now... I'm not sure why would you want to do that. What if the customer messed up, and wants to select another Principle? The original options are now gone, overwritten... Not to mention the listeners hooked-up to the element, which will continue to fire. At first glance, this doesn't look too good of an idea to me...

What is the point including a PHP solution on a Classic ASP question?

This code looks very dated. If you're not using a library (which you should be) functional mysqli would be at the bottom of the list of preferred methods, well below PDO and OOP mysqli. I would also expect to see the HTML generation more separated from the DB logic. And a -1 for introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities. On the frontend, the fetch API has been preferred for ajax calls for a while now (again, if you aren't using a framework of some kind.)

@Congregator Yes, good point, but if someone did select the wrong principle, they could just reload/refresh the page?  The reason I got the idea to consider doing this all with one box is that the only problem with my original idea and using two separate boxes to accomplish this, I didn’t have the foresight to realize that since there are dozens of products from the same principle (company) there are going to be dozens of entries for the same principle. For example, if there are 20 Pepsi products, there will be 20 entries of Pepsi in the Principal field, and there should really only be 1.

@Congregator Sorry scratch that last post. I thought about it more and you’re right for multiple reasons. The one box solution isn’t the way to go.
